# Removing elements from arrays?

Tags: java, arrays

I saw this snippet of code in a forum with the same question, however I needed 50 reputation to comment on the reply. So I posted it here:

```
array = ArrayUtils.removeElement(array, element);
```

I was wondering how this would be applied in code, as this is just the code:
Would it look something like this:

```
myArray = ArrayUtils.removeElement(myArray, 2);
```

or

```
myArray = ArrayUtils.removeElement(int[], 2);
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you misunderstanding how you pass arguments to method invocation expressions? Do you not understand syntax?

Comment: your first line is correct, int[] would result in an error

Comment: But `ìnt[]` is a type - why would you expect this to be an actual parameter in a method call?

Comment: @Ryan 'Maverick' Buxton: btw, you could have "replied" to the original question; it only takes 1 reputation point to "contribute an answer".

Answer (score 2):

The first line

```
myArray = ArrayUtils.removeElement(myArray, 2);
```

is correct syntax. It would return a new version of your array, with the element at index 2 removed. The other line would result in an error, because you aren't actually passing an array object but rather just a type.

Here's the JavaDoc for ArrayUtils if you would like to learn more about this method or other, related methods: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html

Comment: Is there any reason why I can't use this in NetBeans IDE 8.0.1? I type in ArrayUtils.removeElement(xArray, y); and it returns an error 'cannot find symbol?'

Comment: @Ryan'Maverick'Buxton it doesn't look like it's standard with Java, but not sure.